# Rate limit misconfigured bots

Tags: nginx, rate-limiting

We have an Nginx / PHP-FPM behind a load balancer which periodically gets scraped.  Many of the scrapers hit our application's 404 page quiet hard.

Is there a way in Nginx, possibly with the [rate-limiting module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_limit_req_module.html) or a different module, to block all traffic based on x-forward-for after hitting 404 errors at over 100 requests per minute?

The documentation I found for [limit-req-module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_limit_req_module.html) looks like it is based on resource rather than on page return status.

There is enough traffic, that each node is seeing enough 404 traffic that they shouldn't need to communicate about who to collectively block.

Comment: Perhaps fail2ban

Comment: As the IP is in the x-forward-for, would fail2ban be able to update nginx's configuration?

Comment: I'd say the normal method of creating a temporary firewall rule would be sufficient.

Comment: Normal firewall rules would block the traffic from the load balancer, not just the bot.  It doesn't look like there is a way to setup ip based filtering at the load balancer.

Comment: It looks like I found an answer  http://www.michelem.org/2014/08/01/nginx-fail2ban-blocking-ip-behind-aws-load-balancer/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can certainly do this in nginx with the limit_req_zone module.

In nginx.conf setup a zone:

```
limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=one:1000m   rate=100r/m;
```

You can also use `X_Forwarded_For` instead of `binary_remote_addr` too.

In your site config location block just reference the zone:

```
limit_req zone=one burst=10 nodelay;
```

doc:
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_limit_req_module.html

Comment: this does not answer the question. how to rate limit after N 404 have been hit

Answer (score 0):

You can use fail2ban and use following jail with nginx to rate limit misconfigured bots

cp /etc/fail2ban/jail.conf /etc/fail2ban/jail.local
and add this at bottom

```
[nginx-req-limit]

enabled = true
filter = nginx-req-limit
action = iptables-multiport[name=ReqLimit, port="http,https", protocol=tcp]
logpath = /var/log/nginx/*error.log
findtime = 600
bantime = 7200
maxretry = 10
```

references: https://rtcamp.com/tutorials/nginx/fail2ban

Comment: I am not sure about nginx but on apache you must make sure that you actually log the ip of the source, not the load balancer, you would not want the load balancer ip to get blocked.

Comment: iptables does not see the source IP, as it is in the x-forward-for, not in the tcp header.